# When does the compiler creates the copy-constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

For example in the code below :

```
class HowMany {
    static int objectCount;
    public:
        HowMany() { 
            objectCount++; 
        }
        static void print(const string& msg = "") {
             if(msg.size() != 0) 
                 cout << msg << ": ";

             cout << "objectCount = " << objectCount << endl;
        }
        ~HowMany() {
            objectCount--;
            print("~HowMany()");
        }
};

int HowMany::objectCount = 0;

// Pass and return BY VALUE:
HowMany f(HowMany x) {
    x.print("x argument inside f()");
    return x;
}

int main() {
    HowMany h;
    HowMany::print("after construction of h");
    HowMany h2 = f(h);
    HowMany::print("after call to f()");
}
```

Why does the compiler doesn't create the copy-constructor automatically for the class HowMany, and bit-wise copy takes place when the call to f(h) takes place ?

In what cases the compiler creates the default copy-constructor and in what cases it doesn't create?

It gives output as:

> after construction of h: objectCount = 1
>
> x argument inside f(): objectCount = 1
>
> ~HowMany(): objectCount = 0
>
> after call to f(): objectCount = 0
>
> ~HowMany(): objectCount = -1
>
> ~HowMany(): objectCount = -2

Many many thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know itd doesn't create? (BTW, your title says "does" and your question says "doesn't". Fix that first.)

Comment: Check the output for it. I am asking that when it creates automatically and when it doesn't.

Comment: Where is the output? You want us to compile and execute your code to see the output? and then answer it?

Comment: ok i am posting the output also

Comment: First order of business: format the code properly. Currently this it's unreasonable to expect us to read this. I’m also not sure what the question is but I suspect that you have a misconception about the what an auto-generated copy constructor does.

Comment: But it does create a copy constructor. This is why your counter goes negative. What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: Output is also been added, so now when the f(h) is called then the bit-wise copy takes place, and no copy constructor is called for creating x. why?

Comment: This bit-wise copy you're talking about IS the default copy constructor.

Comment: What would you expect to be printed for objectCount, and what do you see?? `objectCount` wouldn't be touched by the auto generated copy constructor!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++98 and C++03 the compiler always creates a copy constructor, that performs a memberwise copy of your fields, unless you specify explicitly that you wrote your own<sup>1</sup>.

This is what happens in your code: the compiler-generated copy constructor doesn't do anything particular - in particular, it doesn't increment `objectCount` - so you end up with a negative object count (all the copied objects didn't increment the counter, but they did decrement it).

To obtain the result you expected, you would have to write something like:

```
HowMany(const HowMany &) { 
        objectCount++; 
}
```

---

1. the default copy constructor is not created even if you write the copy constructor prototype but don't implement it, and/or mark it as private - actually, that's how you create a noncopyable class. C++11 also supports a special syntax to tell the compiler not to generate any copy constructor.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that implementing a copy constructor in this class would look something like `HowMany(const HowMany& objectToCopy) { /* do copying to *this here */ }`.

Comment: Isn't this still true in C++11? Doesn't the compiler generate a copy-constructor unless I write my own?

Comment: @JonathanMee: yes, it should be essentially the same, barring some extra interaction with the move constructor (if a custom move constructor is provided IIRC the default copy constructor is removed).

Answer (score 0):

for every object compiler should create copy constructor, here  also copy constructor created for all object h, x and h2. But for h object copy constructor is no need. And next you are calling a function f with input argument as h. Here copy constructor invokes and it copies the content in h to x object. And for the next object h2 also same thing (here also copy constructor invokes and copies x to h2).  Becuase of this reason only objectcount not incremented. thank you.